# Mac OSX Lion/X11/CImg Library

Tags: xcode, macos, x11, osx-lion

So I'm trying to incorporate the CImg image writing library into my [XCode project](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) However, the header file for the library contains the following include and XCode gives this error warning:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>  Error: File not found
```

My laptop is running OSX Lion 10.8.2 and apparently, apple took away X11 for Lion, so I went on [this site](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and downloaded XQuartz because that's what it said to do on the [Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293).

So after the installation, I restarted my computer and tried to run my XCode project, but I'm still getting the same exact error on that include.

So I'm not sure what I should do now to fix this. If I search in finder for "XLib.h", it appears and I have a folder called X11 which appears in my finder as well, so I feel like I probably have what I need but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The header file `Xlib.h` is in `/opt/X11/include`, so add that path to the *Header Search Paths* in Xcode:

[image]

You'll probably need to add libraries from `/opt/X11/lib` as well...

Comment: For others on the command line, you need to add `-L/opt/X11/lib -lX11`. Also, on newer OSX you need to download and install http://xquartz.macosforge.org

Comment: Hi Trojan, can you tell me where in the `cimg` code do they link the X11 library?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I've never used that package.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger In the demo examples