# Linking error in XCode when using Xlib

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, x11, xlib

The following "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error" occurs when I try to build a small C++ X11/Xlib program in XCode (Version 5).

**Error:**

[image: The displayed linking error]

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Display *d;
    Window w;
    XEvent e;
    string msg = "Hello, World!";
    int s;

    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s = DefaultScreen(d);
    w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 100, 100, 1,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        if (e.type == Expose) {
            XFillRectangle(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 20, 20, 10, 10);
            XDrawString(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 10, 50, msg.c_str(), (int)msg.length());
        }
        if (e.type == KeyPress)
            break;
    }

    XCloseDisplay(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I've added **/opt/X11/include** and **/opt/X11/lib** to the Header Search Paths in Build Settings as suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006245/mac-osx-lion-x11-cimg-library) This linker error is still appearing though.

I'm currently running OSX 10.8.5, and I've installed **XQuartz**.

Am I just missing a build setting, or is there potentially something I'm required to install which I've overlooked?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I was receiving these errors because I wasn't properly setting the flags within XCode.

To solve this issue, go to the Build Settings of your project and add to "Other Linker Flags" the flags:

```
-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you have not linked the library. Please see the build log and see if the library is being linked.

If not, then link it. If it is still linked, then it may not have function.

Comment: Where can I check the build log?

Comment: There is a button Show Log Navigator in Left pane.

Comment: The file is compiling fine, but it isn't linking properly. Do you know how to link the Xlib library?

Comment: Compiling works when done as:
'cc -o "main" "main".cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11'. I tried adding in the flags '-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11' to Other C Flags in Xcode, but I'm still getting errors. Do you know how I would translate something like that command to XCode build settings?

Comment: Goto Build Settings in Xcode, then to Linking->Other Linker Flags and add these options.